# How to find an JSON object by 2 attribute value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON Object and i want to find all elements that have Last Name= Smith and Age 36 in Javascript. Is there any clever way or do i have to loop twice thru all the data?

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Smith",
    "Age": "36",
    "Hobbies": "Fishing, Racecars"
  },
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Derre",
    "Age": "64",
    "Hobbies": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "James",
    "Last Name": "Smith",
    "Age": "36",
    "Hobbies": "Computer"
  },
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Last Name": "Do",
    "Age": "25",
    "Hobbies": "Comics, Music"
  }
]
```

Comment: You don't need any attributes to find the [__JSON object__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). Just type `JSON.` and the needed method name after the dot.

Comment: looping is all you have.

Comment: Filter by iteration.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to limit to matching items:

```
const matches = data.filter(item => item['Last Name'] === "Smith" && item.Age === "36")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for the search parameter

```
{
    'Last Name': 'Smith',
    'Age': '36'
}
```

for a more dynamic filtering over more properties.

```js
var array = [{ Name: "John", "Last Name": "Smith", Age: "36", Hobbies: "Fishing, Racecars" }, { Name: "John", "Last Name": "Derre", Age: "64", Hobbies: "" }, { Name: "James", "Last Name": "Smith", Age: "36", Hobbies: "Computer" }, { Name: "John", "Last Name": "Do", Age: "25", Hobbies: "Comics, Music" }],
    search = { 'Last Name': 'Smith', Age: '36' },
    result = array.filter((keys => o => keys.every(k => o[k] === search[k]))(Object.keys(search)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

The underscore JS library has some handy methods to work with data collections - for instance, the select method

```
var found = _.select(userInfo, function(node){
    return (node.Name === "John" && node.Age === "25")
}); 
console.dir (found);
```

Comment: The question never tagged Lodash/Underscore so it doesn't make sense to have it in an answer, especially when it can be done natively.

Comment: An alternative, since the usual method has already been published.

Comment: @Redr01d it's just a common practice to not introduce a new library/framework unless tagged or explicitly ok'd by OP.

Comment: Thanks I'll know =(